# How to get all android contacts but without those which are on SIM

Tags: android, sim-card

It is possible to do it in one query?

As far as I know content uri of sim contacts is `content://icc/adn`

Comment: Please Checkout a library on [Github](https://github.com/nitiwari-dev/android-contact-extractor) to fetch contacts with simple easy to use api.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is very easy! :)

```
Cursor cursor = mContentResolver.query(
   RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
   new String[]{RawContacts._ID,RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE},
   RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " <> 'com.anddroid.contacts.sim' "
    + " AND " + RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " <> 'com.google' " //if you don't want to google contacts also
   ,
   null,
   null);
```

Comment: Can you please write the code of how to get the number and name from this cursor.  i hvae write the code as "while(cursor.moveToNext()){String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
Log.i("all contacts",phoneNumber+"->"+name);
   }

Comment: but got the error like ": Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 46, numColumns = 2

Comment: 'com.anddroid.contacts.sim' is a manual value. There is any constant refer to it.

Comment: @tana How do you know which possible constants are available for the current device? Is there a way to get the correct one for SIM/local storage of contacts, no matter the device?

Comment: sorry I dont know the constant