# How to read android sim contacts and phone contacts separately

Tags: java, android

I want to read all sim contacts and phone contacts separately in Android. I searched for this and found lots of people having problem with this and I couldn't find any solution yet. I fond some answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4409453/559185), but it doesn't work for me.
When I test this it give me google contacts:

```
RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = 'com.google' "
```

But when I test this it does not give me sim contacts:

```
RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = 'com.android.contacts.sim' "
```

Then I found RawContacts are contacts that created by sync adapter in [here](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/133816827efc8eb9/8671f76b4111f215?pli=1). That may be the problem. So can anyone tell me the way of getting

- All simcontacts
- All phone contacts

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe there's a typo in ACCOUNT_TYPE? Try `com.android.contacts.sim`.

Comment: ohh sorry i have made a mistake in typing ,but that is not the case :).i will edit this

Comment: No friend :( .But i finally decide to read contacts with and without having Account_Type separately ,like ACCOUNT_TYPE is null,and ACCOUNT_TYPE='the_account'.But i think you can do it by reading all account_type null contacts(list1) and reading all sim contacts(list2) and then removing list2 from list1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**for Phone contacts**

```
try
{
    String[] PROJECTION=new String[] {Contacts._ID,
        Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        Phone.NUMBER
    };

    Cursor c=managedQuery(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            String ClsPhonename = null;
            String ClsphoneNo = null;

            do 
            {
                ClsPhonename = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                ClsphoneNo = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));


                ClsphoneNo.replaceAll("\\D", "");
                ClsPhonename=ClsPhonename.replaceAll("&", "");
                ClsPhonename.replace("|","");
                String ClsPhoneName=ClsPhonename.replace("|","");

                }   

            } while(c.moveToNext());
        }
```

**for sim contacts**

String ClsSimPhonename = null;
String ClsSimphoneNo = null;

```
    Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn"); 
    Cursor cursorSim = this.getContentResolver().query(simUri,null,null,null,null);

    while (cursorSim.moveToNext()) 
    {      
        ClsSimPhonename =cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("name"));
        ClsSimphoneNo = cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("number"));
        ClsSimphoneNo.replaceAll("\\D","");
        ClsSimphoneNo.replaceAll("&", "");
        ClsSimPhonename=ClsSimPhonename.replace("|","");
            System.out.println("SimContacts"+ClsSimPhonename);
            System.out.println("SimContactsNo"+ClsSimphoneNo);
            dts.createDatabse("MyCellFamily",getApplicationContext());

    }        
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay.in the first example i'm getting all contacts.(not only contacts saved to phone but also sim and synced with google)

Comment: Is there no way to get Phone contacts except contacts saved to sim or synced with google (or other sync accounts).

Comment: how to remove this contact ?

Comment: @bindal  the code which you posted is good for export contact but i want to know if we have dual sim then how we ll  get both sim URI or how i will save or read both  sim card sepratly

Answer (score 4):

I found many phones use `"com.android.contacts.sim"` in `RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE` for sim contacts. But I also found that HTC use "com.anddroid.contacts.sim" (**misspelled** for android). That is weird.

Comment: and some uses "vnd.sec.contact.sim" also.

Comment: How do you find all possible accounts of SIM&local, that a new contact can be saved into, no matter which device it runs on?