# Android get contact list without sim contact

Tags: android

how to get contact list without contact from simcard?

so far my cursor looks like this

```
public final static Uri CONTENT = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
public final static String ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
public final static String NAME = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME;
public final static String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;
public final static String PHOTO_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO_URI;
public final static String STARRED = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.STARRED;

String mSelectionClause = NAME + " IS NULL";
mOrderBy = NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(CONTENT, null, mSelectionClause, null, mOrderBy);
```

what should i add to query to remove sim contact from result?

Comment: did you check this article?? http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html

Comment: @OleksiiKropachov yes but i cannot find there any info about my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found folution in

[android showing both sim and phone contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14914880/android-showing-both-sim-and-phone-contacts)

just added

```
    private final String excludeSim = ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " <> 'com.android.contacts.sim' AND "
    + ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " <> 'com.anddroid.contacts.sim' AND " // HTC
    + ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " <> 'vnd.sec.contact.sim' AND "
    + ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " <> 'USIM Account' "; 
    ...
    String mSelectionClause = NAME + " IS NULL AND " + excludeSim;
```