# Display phone contacts only in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am new to android.I need phone contacts to be displayed in my application.The problem I face here is google contacts are also coming with the phone contacts in my application.I don't know how to filter this problem.I need to display only my phone contacts.Please help me.
Thanks in advance

```
 list = new ArrayList<contactlist>();
 adptr = new customcontactadptr(this, R.layout.listcontactitem, list);
 Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
 ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
 String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
 Cursor cur = cr.query(uri, null, null, null, sortOrder);
 if(cur.getCount() > 0)
 {
  cur.moveToFirst();
  do
  {
   if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
     cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) 
   {
    String contactid = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    contactlist con = new contactlist();
    nme = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    Log.e("contactid",contactid);
    String status = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_STATUS));
    Long statuslabel = cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_STATUS_LABEL));
    if(status!=null)
    {
     Log.e("status", status);
    }
    else if(statuslabel!=null)
    {
     Log.e("status label", Long.toString(statuslabel));
    }
 Cursor pCur = cr.query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
            null,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", 
            new String[]{contactid}, null);
 pCur.moveToFirst();
 do 
 {
  int phone_type = pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
  if(phone_type == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
  {

   no = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
   Log.e("Name",nme);
   Log.e("Number",no);
   con.setchecked(false);
      con.setname(nme);
      con.setno(n);
      list.add(con);
      adptr.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
 }while (pCur.moveToNext());
 pCur.close();

   }
  }while(cur.moveToNext());
 }
 setListAdapter(adptr);
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4409453/1265724)

Comment: @ShreyaShah I have added my code

Comment: @ Ram kiran You link has helped me.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code ....

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Creating a button click listener for the "Add Contact" button
        OnClickListener addClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Getting reference to Name EditText
                EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);

                // Getting reference to Mobile EditText
                EditText etMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_mobile_phone);

                // Getting reference to HomePhone EditText
                EditText etHomePhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_home_phone);

                // Getting reference to HomeEmail EditText
                EditText etHomeEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_home_email);

                // Getting reference to WorkEmail EditText
                EditText etWorkEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_work_email);

                ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
                new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

                int rawContactID = ops.size();

                // Adding insert operation to operations list
                // to insert a new raw contact in the table ContactsContract.RawContacts
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                        .build());

                // Adding insert operation to operations list
                // to insert display name in the table ContactsContract.Data
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, etName.getText().toString())
                        .build());

                // Adding insert operation to operations list
                // to insert Mobile Number in the table ContactsContract.Data
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, etMobile.getText().toString())
                        .withValue(Phone.TYPE, CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                        .build());

                // Adding insert operation to operations list
                // to  insert Home Phone Number in the table ContactsContract.Data
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, etHomePhone.getText().toString())
                        .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_HOME)
                        .build());

                // Adding insert operation to operations list
                // to insert Home Email in the table ContactsContract.Data
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(Email.ADDRESS, etHomeEmail.getText().toString())
                        .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_HOME)
                        .build());

                // Adding insert operation to operations list
                // to insert Work Email in the table ContactsContract.Data
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactID)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(Email.ADDRESS, etWorkEmail.getText().toString())
                        .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_WORK)
                        .build());

                try{
                    // Executing all the insert operations as a single database transaction
                    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Contact is successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        // Creating a button click listener for the "Add Contact" button
        OnClickListener contactsClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Creating an intent to open Android's Contacts List
                Intent contacts = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

                // Starting the activity
                startActivity(contacts);
            }
        };

        // Getting reference to "Add Contact" button
        Button btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);

        // Getting reference to "Contacts List" button
        Button btnContacts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_contacts);

        // Setting click listener for the "Add Contact" button
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(addClickListener);

        // Setting click listener for the "List Contacts" button
        btnContacts.setOnClickListener(contactsClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```