# SQLite avoiding duplicate entries in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on a project to get appointment and in the appointment project client get appointment of doctor.

In case date is `03/04/2014` and time is `04:00 pm`  and other client get appointment and if he insert date `03/04/2014` and time is `04:00 pm`  at that time how to avoid this record to insert into database ?

Comment: use unix timestamp formate

Answer (score 1):

I have given one answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25012061/how-to-avoid-duplicate-contact-name-data-while-loading-contact-info-to-listvi/25093376#25093376) which helps to avoid duplicate entries by using SQLite. Check once. It may help you.

You can use `UNIQUE` constraint when you will create the column in database table. Which will help to avoid duplicate entries at the time of inserting.