# How to get contacts from contact list in Android? using Contact Provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contacts, contactscontract

I had to fetch contact list from android using contact provider, but it was showing me duplicate entries. So, How can I filter those duplicate entries.

For example, **ABCD - 123467890, 1234567890, 1234567890**

how to filter duplicate phone number using contact Provider?

And Can I fetch only phone memory contact list?

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: i think you have to edit the question title, you are asking about duplicate issue, not about the whole fetch

Comment: You can find some solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25012061/how-to-avoid-duplicate-contact-name-data-while-loading-contact-info-to-listvi)

Comment: Follow Dalma Racz comment, this will also lead you to the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious to get duplicate contacts when you fetch them. Since, same contact (same number, different name or different number, same name) might be stored in either in google contacts, phone contacts or in sim contacts.

In order to eliminate duplicates in your application, use local database (SQLite provided by android) and make phone number as unique, no duplicates will be stored.

For more information refer this post [How to get all android contacts but without those which are on SIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338563/how-to-get-all-android-contacts-but-without-those-which-are-on-sim?lq=1)

Following Dalma Racz comment, will also lead you to the solution.