# In Android, how do you select only PHONE contacts?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am querying the Contacts out of the built in Contacts provider URI in Android. I want to get just the PHONE contacts; is there any consistent way to do this? It seems from what I can find that the account name for phone contacts differs from manufacturer to manufacturer (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614089/finding-account-nature-of-a-contact-group)). Is there a way to get PHONE contacts (not SIM, Facebook, Twitter or others) in a consistent, reliable, manufacturer- and device- agnostic way?

Comment: Do you want to get all of the contacts that have a phone number? Or do you mean all of the contacts that were imported from the SIM card?

Comment: I was looking to get all contacts that were stored in the "on-phone" address book, regardless of whether they have phone numbers, emails, or whatnot. I thought I could do it by joining my query with the `accounts` table and looking for the account name `vnd.sec.contact.phone`, but reading online, it looks like that account name is manufacturer (and possibly device?) specific.

Answer (score -1):

```
            Cursor cursor = null;

                try {

                    String selection = ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = ?";
                    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { id };
                    String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER};

                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                            projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

                    if (cursor == null || !cursor.moveToFirst())
                        return;

                    String phone = cursor.getString(0);



                } finally {
                    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
                        try {
                            cursor.close();
                        } catch (Throwable ignore) {
                            // Ignored.
                        }
                }
```

Where "?" is user ID, you can put this code into a loop.

Comment: Unless I'm misreading this code, wouldn't this only find me all contacts from any source (phone, sim, facebook, twitter, etc) but only who have phone numbers? I want to find contacts ONLY from the phone, regardless of whether they have a phone number or not.

Comment: You have right, I misunderstood your question. I thought that you was trying to get Phone number of a particular user (ID). I will try to find a answer for you. Sorry about that.