# How to get All Sim Contacts in Android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-contacts

How to list sim contacts in Android programmatically? I got the code to get phone contacts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133163/how-to-get-phone-contacts-in-android/13737976#comment18889423_13737976) but I need sim contacts too with this.

Answer (score 6):

```
Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn");

  Cursor cursorSim = this.getContentResolver().query(simUri, null, null,null, null);

         while (cursorSim.moveToNext()) {           
             listName.add(cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("name")));
             listContactId.add(cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("_id")));      
             listMobileNo.add(cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("number")));
            }
```

> simply now following code to get the simcard details..It works fine

Comment: i think its require the permission: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/> need both of @iDroidExplorer

Comment: @QuokMoon this code working fine but suppose i have to save contact to sim based on Sim selection then  how to get sim URI for both  sim so that i can save contact to sim

Comment: This doesn't seem to help. All the fields here can't be mapped precisely to contacts. You get only phone numbers from here. What if you have 2 contacts with same phone number, one in SIM-card, and another outside?

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String>listName=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String>listContactId=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String>listMobileNo=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String>idArr=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String>nameArr=new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn");

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursorSim = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
               null, null, null, null);
       // Cursor cursorSim = this.getContentResolver().query(simUri, null, null,null, null);

               while (cursorSim.moveToNext()) {           
                //   listName.add(cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("name")));
                 //  listContactId.add(cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("_id")));      
                 //  listMobileNo.add(cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex("number")));
                   String id = cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                   String name = cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));


                 //  String number=cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                   idArr.add(id);
                   nameArr.add(name);

                 //  listMobileNo.add(number);


                   if (Integer.parseInt(cursorSim.getString(cursorSim.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

                   System.out.println("name : " + name + ", ID : " + id);

                   // get the phone number
                   Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                          ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                                          new String[]{id}, null);
                   while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                         String phone = pCur.getString(
                                pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                         System.out.println("phone=" + phone);
                         listMobileNo.add(phone);
                   }
                   pCur.close();

                  }
               }
               System.out.println("idArr="+idArr);
               System.out.println("nameArr="+nameArr);

             //  System.out.println("listName="+listName);
              // System.out.println("listContactId="+listContactId);
               System.out.println("listMobileNo="+listMobileNo);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Add this code to your mainifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Comment: About "content://icc/adn", this returns only those that are on the SIM card, but what if I want to get all contacts, and show where they are saved? Querying ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI instead, I can see all kinds of contacts, including those on SIM card an outside...

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried this

```
TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Also include READ_PHONE_STATE permission in manifest file.

Comment: This code is to retrive the sim number not the contacts stored in device