# Reading contacts from the 2nd (inactive) Sim

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have used the code form the answers mentioned in the question
[How to get All Sim Contacts in Android Progrmmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757022/how-to-get-all-sim-contacts-in-android-progrmmatically)

But for my use case I want to fetch the contacts from SIM only (from both SIMs in case it is a dual SIM phone).

When I use

```
Uri simUri = Uri.parse("content://icc/adn");
```

I am getting the contacts from active SIM only

Answer (score 1):

As it has been said before, the Android SDK doesn't support dual SIMS, as this is something that the manufactures has done customizing the device.

As proposed here:

[Dual SIM card Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255147/dual-sim-card-android)

You can try contact the manufactures and ask them directly.