# Getting all contacts GMAIL

Tags: android, google-api

How can I get all contacts from Gmail? Is there any library that facilitates this process ? I do not want to get contacts from the device addressbook but GMAIL .

Answer (score 0):

You can't get it from Gmail, because gmail uses the contacts provider of the phone.
What you need is to read the contacts provider and filter by google account.

To do this you need the rights: READ_CONTACTS and READ_ACCOUNTS.

Look here: [How to get phone contacts in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133163/how-to-get-phone-contacts-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

From the Google developers site this might be helpful: 
[Google contacts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts)

Or dit you want to only [export](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/24911?hl=en) your contacts?