# How to Fetch User Contacts from my android application

Tags: android, mysql

i want to fetch users contacts through my android application and i also give permission in Manifests file in android
 
i can't know how can i see them contacts please help me

Comment: Did you try to search for this? Dont tell SO that you are not able to find any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133163/how-to-get-phone-contacts-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below Snippet :

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,      null, null, null);
if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
while (cur.moveToNext()) {
String id = cur.getString(
                       cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    String name = cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
        //Query phone here.  Covered next
        }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.example.harismahmood.fhfountainhouse;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class ContactListview extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public int getSelectedItemPosition() {
        return super.getSelectedItemPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public long getSelectedItemId() {
        return super.getSelectedItemId();
    }

    ListView lv;
    Cursor cursor1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_listview);

        cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI ,null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor1);
        String[] from = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};

        int[] to = {android.R.id.text1 , android.R.id.text2};

        SimpleCursorAdapter listadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor1,from,to);

        setListAdapter(listadapter);
        lv = getListView();
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    }

}
```